# Unable to load google maps on laravel application

Tags: javascript, laravel, api, google-maps, laravel-mix

I'm trying to load the google maps js API on a Laravel application, and I just keep getting an error 'initMap is not a function'.

I think it's probably an issue that's related to the visibility of initMap function from the global scope.
Error:
[image: the error]

app.blade.php
[image: app.blade.php]

asset/js/ap/js
[image: asset/js/ap.js]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems obvious but i think you should try loading your

```
<script>{{asset(js/app.js)}}</script>
```

after the googleMap js file

(edit) it's likely a async issue, async scripts may be run in any order, regardless of the order in which they appear in the HTML.

if you want to keep this behaviour you maybe wrap you init() call in a window.onload callback and remove the &callback=initmap from the google map script

```
window.onload = () => {
    init()
}
```

another solution is to place the googlemap script before your ap.js and remove the async defer attribute from your ap.js script tag

hope this solve your issue

Comment: my guess: its likely a async issue, you should try one of this: remove the async defer keyword for your ap.js and place it after the google api script (just like the google map api docs) or remove the &callback=initmap from your google api script and wrap your init call in a window.onload callback

Comment: I try window.onload=initMap () and it works good, but the error steel showing.